# How to create a prisma model from a SQL view

Tags: view, introspection, prisma

Is it possible to have 'prisma introspect' create models for views in Postgres ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently not, but we have a request for that [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/678) that you can follow for more updates. As a workaround, you can manually add that view to `schema.prisma` as a `model` and then query as you do for normal models.

Comment: Great, that's simple enough. Thankyou

Comment: Found this too : https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/advanced-database-tasks/sql-views-postgres

Comment: @Ryan can you describe how we add the model to the shema.prisma and how we generate the prisma client? I have create a view into the database, then i declare it as a model into prisma.schema and the i tried to generate the prisma client, with the command npx prisma generate. But i get the following error:

The model with database name "test_view" could not be defined because another model with this name exists: "test_view"